# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'domains' exceeded the quota

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome, local-storage, domexception

This error shows every time in chrome when i open the console.

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting 
the value of 'domains' exceeded the quota. at HTMLScriptElement.a.onload (https://dl.metabar.ru/static/storage/js/storage.min.js version=201804162002:1:6177)
a.onload....

Why is that?

Comment: localstorage has a limited quota of space, less than 5 MB.

Comment: what should I do to fix an error?

Comment: Check if its storing some large media file like image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually your Storage is full and most likely it is full because of some of your browser extensions.

Answer (score 5):

I have cleared my localstorage of the browser.. Open your developer's tool and clear from Applications -> Storage -> LocalStorage -> Clear All..

I re-ran the application and it worked.

[image]