# Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of '136114546' exceeded the quota Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue on the frontend of my application, the application is running really well on my local machine without any errors but on the server, there are some issues like click events not setting items. When I check the console, however, I get this error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of '136114546' exceeded the quota.`
I found this [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923280/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-setitem-on-storage-setting-the-val) where the answer is storage being full but I have unlimited storage and it is working well on my local machine.

What could be the solution to this kind of error? Since it is working well on my local server, could the problem be with the server?

Comment: It's because localStorage has a size limit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49923280/4393351